# jQuery cycle prev/next button images

Tags: php, jquery, css, drupal-7, cycle

I'm using Drupal 7 and Field Slideshow plugin. I published my slide and working. It's have a pager and that's name 'Prev' and 'Next'

I don't want text, must image. How can i do it?

```
<div id="field-slideshow-<?php print $slideshow_id; ?>-controls" class="field-slideshow-controls">
  <a href="#" class="prev"><?php print t('Prev'); ?></a>
  <?php if (!empty($controls_pause)) : ?>
    <a href="#" class="play"><?php print t('Play'); ?></a>
    <a href="#" class="pause"><?php print t('Pause'); ?></a>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <a href="#" class="next"><?php print t('Next'); ?></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="field-slideshow-<?php print $slideshow_id; ?>-controls" class="field-slideshow-controls">
  <a href="#" class="prev"></a>
  <?php if (!empty($controls_pause)) : ?>
    <a href="#" class="play"><?php print t('Play'); ?></a>
    <a href="#" class="pause"><?php print t('Pause'); ?></a>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <a href="#" class="next"></a>
</div>
```

And styles like this:

```
.prev {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background: transparent url('path/to/prev/image.png') no-repeat center center;
}

.next {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background: transparent url('path/to/next/image.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Or you can have something like this:

```
<div id="field-slideshow-<?php print $slideshow_id; ?>-controls" class="field-slideshow-controls">
      <a href="#" class="prev"><img scr="path/to/prev/image.png" alt="<?php print t('Prev'); ?>" /></a>
      <?php if (!empty($controls_pause)) : ?>
        <a href="#" class="play"><?php print t('Play'); ?></a>
        <a href="#" class="pause"><?php print t('Pause'); ?></a>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <a href="#" class="next"><img scr="path/to/next/image.png" alt="<?php print t('Next'); ?>"  /></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? What does it mean - remove Prev/Next button? Why it should be shown if it is removed?

Comment: And what about styles? Do you apply proposed styles to it?

Comment: Are those styles really applied, have you specified correct path to images? Also - I placed width/height just to show that there should be some values specified. If your images are large, you may simply see some part of it which is transparent or have the same color. Try to debug it with developer tools (F12 in all browsers, you may need to install Firebug extension for FireFox)

Comment: That code should work. Try to change background to something like this:  `background: yellow url('path/to/next/image.png') no-repeat center center;` and see if you have yellow box appearing. I can't help you without seeing exact code you have

Comment: For instance, here it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/p9EGu/ (except that there are no images - simple yellow boxes are shown and if correct path will be specified, images will be shown too)